# AWS config for ec2, s3, loadbalancer using troposphere

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I am trying to configure `AWS::Config` for my instances and buckets.

But i didn't find any reference in troposphare,

How can i create `ConfigRule`

I have template for config in cloudformation.

```
AWSConfig = t.add_resource(
config.ConfigRule(
    'ConfigRule',
    ConfigRuleName=Client+'S3BucketRule',
    Description='S3 Public Read Prohibited Bucket Rule',
    InputParameters='{}',
    MaximumExecutionFrequency=config.TWELVE_HOURS,
    Scope=config.Scope(
        ComplianceResourceId=Ref(LogBucket),
        ComplianceResourceTypes=['AWS::S3::Bucket'],
    ),
    Source=config.Source(
        Owner='AWS',
        SourceIdentifier='S3_BUCKET_PUBLIC_READ_PROHIBITED',
        ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find the relevant resource definition here:

https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/config.py#L56

Note, in general, troposphere tries to be a 1:1 mapping for Cloudformation resources/parameters.  So if the Cloudformation resource is `AWS::Config::ConfigRule` then you can almost always guess that the relevant troposphere resource import is `from troposphere.config import ConfigRule`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @phobologic 

But can you tell me how can i configure for at least one resource. 
I tried this: 
```config = t.add_resource(
    config.ConfigRule(
        'ConfigRule',
        ConfigRuleName=Client+'AccessConfigRule',
        Description='Keep track of Modification for AWS service',
        InputParameters='',
        MaximumExecutionFrequency='',
        Scope='',
        Source='',
        )
    )```
How can i do further!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking fully - did that not work correctly?  Was there an error message?  I actually don't know ConfigRule very well off the top of my head, but without knowing what is not working for you/what exactly you're trying to do, not sure how I can help!

Comment: I have updated the code, Now see i want to configure `AWS::Config` for my resources like, s3, ec2 instances loadbalancer and etc, But i am stuck here at how can i add the `configRule` for each resources.